# My windows git doesn't commit even though changes are staged

Tags: git

Example of what I do.

```
MSYS /c/repos/git/qa (feature1)
$ git status  
On branch feature1 Your branch is up to date with 'origin/feature1'.

Changes to be committed:   (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   code/file1.py
        new file:   code/file2.xml


MSYS /c/repos/git/qa (feature1)
$ git commit -m 'added widget'

MSYS /c/repos/git/qa (feature1)
$
```

git log, doesn't show my message. If I use a GUI tool I can commit.
I tried git clean -f and it does nothing as well. So it seems that it is some write permission, but I started git bash as Administrator as well to no effect.

Comment: Try double quotes `git commit -m "added widget"`

Comment: @Paolo No, the double quotes are not needed. Actually the space is not needed and is not recommended; you are supposed to say `-m'added widget'`. But that has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @Paolo Thanks I tried that but it makes no difference, also I'm using git bash so single quotes should work.

Comment: What does `git status` say afterwards ?

Comment: @LeGEC exactly the same as before the commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a pre-commit hook that failed.

Doing a `git commit -m'added widget' --no-verify` works. For some reason GitAhead does this automatically.

It would be great if git can report what went wrong.